# Why does the 2p orbital of chlorine form a sigma bond with Be in BeCl2 and not 3p?

Tags: molecular-structure, orbitals, hybridization

So I was reading my textbook when I came across, "Each of the sp hybridized orbitals overlap with the 2p orbitals of chlorine axially and form 2 Be-Cl sigma bonds."

Now this confused me because the electronic configuration of Chlorine is [Ne]3s2`3p5`.

So, technically, shouldn't the 3p orbital of both chlorines attach to the sp orbital of beryllium? Why does the 2p orbital overlap? Also, how does it achieve this? The 2p orbitals of chlorine are all full (i.e. they all have 2 electrons). Does one 2pz electron get excited into the 3pz orbital?

I am very confused here and have tried reading online but haven't found any satisfactory answer. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Smells like a typo.

Comment: I thought so too at first, but in the very next section it says, "The three hybrid orbitals formed are oriented in a trigonal planar arrangement and overlap with 2p orbitals of chlorine to form three B-Cl bonds." This is about sp2 hybridized BCl3. A typo could've occurred once, but twice?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: Generally if you quote a textbook, it's good to provide the title, author, publisher, etc.